# How to get rid of white space between css horizontal list items?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, navigationbar

I've got the following test page and css.  When displayed, there is a 4px gap between each list item.  How do I get the items to be next to each other?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">     

<html>
      <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/test.css" />
      </head>

      <body>
        <div>
          <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="#">One1</a></li>
            <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="#">Three</a></li>
            <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="#">Four</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

The css:

```
ul.nav, ul li.nav {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li.nav {
  background-color: red;
}

a.nav {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
}

a:hover.nav {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to use `display:block` and `float:left` on the `li`s to remove the space. When they're inline the browser treats them as words, and so leaves space in between.

Also see [my similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097006/removing-whitespace-between-html-elements-when-using-line-breaks).

Answer (score 18):

Combine @Skilldrick and @teedyay and you have your answer and explanation.
If `<li>`s are treated as words than any white space around them is condensed to one space.

So I guess this is a feature that looks like a bug.

To remove the space either put all your `<li>`s in a chain with no white space between them.
OR
Reduce the font size on the `<ul>` to 0 and restore the size on the `<li>`s

Comment: reducing the font size and restoring it did the trick for me, thanks

Comment: I know this question is a little old but there is one more alternative - putting `<!--` after each `</li>` and `-->` before each `<li>`. Note that I didn't say it was a good solution! It has become my preferred method compared to the above alternatives, however.

Comment: float left also works, but came with undesired side effects for me. Font size zero did the trick. thanks

Answer (score 12):

You can also set `font-size:0` for the `<ul>` tag.

Comment: sorry, didnt entirely read @David answers.

Comment: was the better solution for me

Comment: What about the browser support? i have read somewhere that it doesn't work in IE <= 7

Comment: this is the best solution for me....thanks....

`float:left;` also working...but it doesn't work if i want to make `white-space:nowrap`

but `font-size:0;` solved my problem.

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid this is dirty too, but I'll be (pleasantly) surprised if there's a clean fix to this.

Put all your `<li>`s on one line:

```
<li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="#">One1</a></li><li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="#">Two</a></li><li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="#">Three</a></li><li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="#">Four</a></li>
```

Sorry.