# How can I create a horizontal menu with each item being equal width and spacing inbetween?

Tags: html, css, navigation, html-lists

Here's what I've got so far: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnpenner/Nk2Wy/)

2 problems with it though:

1. I've hard-coded the width of each `li` to `33%`, which I'd prefer not to do so that I can easily add more items.
2. I want to put some spacing between each item (a gap in the background color), but as soon as I add a margin, one item will be bumped down a line. How do I get around that?

```css
#main-nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:  auto;
}
#main-nav li {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
#main-nav li a {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #e0e0f0;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #021020;
}
#main-nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #498cd5;
    color: #ddeeee;
}
```

```html
<ul id="main-nav">
    <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Which browsers/versions do you need to support? IE7?

Comment: @thirtydot: As many as possible, although I'm less concerned with older browsers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/f6qmm/

`display: table` is being used to evenly space a dynamic number of `li`s. Unfortunately, that [doesn't work](http://caniuse.com/css-table) in IE7, so `*float: left` is used (for only IE7 and lower) so that at least they're all on one line - though it still looks horrendous.

`padding-left: 5px` is applied to every `li`, then `li:first-child { padding-left: 0 }` removes it for only the first `li`.

```css
#main-nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    overflow: hidden
}
#main-nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    *float: left; /* improve IE7 */
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 5px
}
#main-nav li:first-child {
    padding-left: 0
}
#main-nav li a {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #e0e0f0;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #021020;
}
#main-nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #498cd5;
    color: #ddeeee;
}
```

```html
<ul id="main-nav">
    <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
</ul>

<hr />

<ul id="main-nav">
    <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">five</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice! I prefer to do `#main-nav li+li { padding-left: 3px; }` over the `:first-child` thing though. I think it's better supported, and requires less code. I've never seen or heard anyone else use this method though...

Comment: `+` and `:first-child` have virtually identical browser support. Both don't work in IE6, and do work in IE7. Though the `+` solution is a line shorter :)

Comment: Just noticed that this method makes the first element a few pixels larger than the rest.

Comment: table-layout: fixed; ... this was the part I was missing

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nk2Wy/1/.

This approach allows you adding an arbitrary number of items. If they do not fit on the line anymore, because they are so many or because the browser window is quite small, they are shown on further lines.

If you add a `width: 50px` to the `a` style, all those items have the same width. Right now, the width depends on the actual text.

See the question (and answers) [How to get rid of white space between css horizontal list items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043707/how-to-get-rid-of-white-space-between-css-horizontal-list-items) as well.

Due to this, I updated the fiddle once again: http://jsfiddle.net/Nk2Wy/3/.

Comment: ok...that seems to create an arbitrary gap of 1 space, which is OK for me in this case, but...i'd like to actually define the space in pixels. **edit:** actually, i think that only works because there's a left-over unused 1%.

Comment: the items are supposed to fill the entire width of container AND be the same width, not just some pre-set pixel width. the 'white space between css horizontal items' is kind of irrelevant as i've already solved that with floats, which you just told me to remove, thus you've added a problem and solved none.