# All menu items with the same width

Tags: html, css, menu

I've created a responsive menu with 100% width. Is it possible to have all same length for each menu item. At the moment the menu items with the more words have more width than the ones with less words. I hope this makes some sense. Heres my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldu3o1jm/2/)

My CSS:

```
nav {
margin: 0 auto; 
text-align: center;
background: #fff;
height:70px;
  width:100%;
}

nav ul {
width: 100%;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: table;
vertical-align: top;
background: rgba(148,148,149,1);
}

nav ul li {
display: table-cell;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

}

nav ul li a {
display: block; 
padding: 10px 7px;
color: #000;
text-decoration:none;

}
nav ul li~li { border-left: 1px solid #857D7A; }

nav .active a {
background: rgba(180,85,12,1);
color:#fff;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <nav>
<ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Asdfsdfsd</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pefsdfsfsdfsdf dgdgdfgo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hsdfsdfe</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Csfsdfsdfsfs</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Visdfsdfcdsfdsfyy</a> </li>
   </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885785/how-can-i-create-a-horizontal-menu-with-each-item-being-equal-width-and-spacing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your "nav ul li":

```
width: 20%;
```

**Edit:**
You can go another way as wellby adding this to "nav ul":

```
table-layout:fixed;
```

The content of the last item is too long, you can hide by adding this to "nav ul li":

```
overflow-x: hidden
```

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/vqrde5u4/

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the width of the li tags.

In your CSS:

```
nav li { width: 20%; /*100% width / 5 elements*/ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
nav ul{
    //other stuff
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

Now, you should also add something like `overflow:hidden;` so the text won't run off the edge.