# WordPress Avada - Fusion Main Menu: how to achieve centered positioning between top level horizontal menu items?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, fusion

Test Site Example: [1] http://test.hauptstadtventures.com

Since [1] is a child theme of Avada Fusion [2] https://avada.theme-fusion.com, one of the top-selling themes out there, I hope this is relevant for other developers as well.

I have the following problem:
The menu item 2 should be centered between the logo and the neighboring item 1. Same logic should apply to item 3.

> |[item 1] <----------->  [item 2] <----------->   [LOGO] <-----------> [items 3]<-----------> [item 4]|

[This is the current as-is state. Items 2 and 3 are not centered bewtween the logo and their neighboring items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYIBr.png)

Constraints:

- The main menu is 100% (with a pixel-based padding left of item 1 and
  right of item 4).
- Logo is at the center of the window / content, meaning: it does not move just as the center item [BASIC SERVICES] in the fiddle of the top answer of [3] by @Danield.
- Items 1 is aligned left and items 4 is aligned right.
- Items 2 and 3 are floating between the logo and their neighboring items, always centered, taking the anchor text length into account.
- Items 2 and 3 stay centered when the window width is being changed.
- No changes to the HTML/DOM tree, no javascript/jQuery positioning solutions, I am looking for an elegant CSS-only solution that can be applied in [1]. I am aware that there are already potentially interferring CSS rules, please consider it as part of the challenge.

Development environment:

- Avada version: 5.7.1
- WP version: 4.9.8

I had a look at the following approaches, tired to implement them, but had no success so far:

[3] [How to stretch a fixed number of horizontal navigation items evenly and fully across a specified container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060923/how-to-stretch-a-fixed-number-of-horizontal-navigation-items-evenly-and-fully-ac)

[4] [How can I create a horizontal menu with each item being equal width and spacing inbetween?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885785/how-can-i-create-a-horizontal-menu-with-each-item-being-equal-width-and-spacing)

I also developed a jQuery solution that is positioning the css left values of items 2 and 3, but there must be an elegant css solution. Right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would fiddle around with `justify-content: space-around;` or `justify-content: space-between;` on the `ul`, and remove the `flex:1` on the `li`s

Comment: sorry - it might be `justify-content: space-evenly;`

Comment: @Stender thanks! I'll implement it and will give you feedback.

Comment: @Stender I'm nearly there. I've put `justify-content: space-between;` into the <ul> tag [1] https://imgur.com/QRUY1CD . Now the spacing between logo and item elements is perfect [2] https://imgur.com/4ppfUza, but the logo is not centered within the window / content as it is before deactivating `flex:1` for the <li> tags [3] https://imgur.com/QbQUVCO . I should have been more explicit about this constraint, I update my question. Any idea how to move on?