# Centerize table vertically and horizontally in div

Tags: css, html-table, alignment, vertical-alignment, centering

You may think it was duplicated, but I don't thinks so, because **I'm talking about tables not images!**

I tried to set a table in center of div horizontally and vertically with the below codes.
The codes work fine for images but when I put a table instead of image, it seems it can not see the tables and then put the span size to 100% and table display below of div not in center of div.

Codes:

```
<style>
.wraptocenter {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:155px;
    height: 160px;
    background-color:#999;
    display: block;
}
.wraptocenter * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.wraptocenter span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
}

</style>
<!--[if lt IE 8]><style>
.wraptocenter span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}
</style><![endif]-->
<div class="wraptocenter">
    <span></span>
    <table border="1" width=" 70%">
        <tr height="10px">
            <td width="10px" height="10px"></td>
            <td width="10px" height="10px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="10px">
            <td height="10px"></td>
            <td height="10px"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

If you put a images every thing work fine but for tables NOT!

Comment: check [this](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/FW2Af/

Your code only center elements with `display:inline-block`, such as images. But a table has `display:table`.

Then, you can solve it creating a `div` with `display:inline-block` which contains your table.

And if you want table's width to be 70% of wraptocenter`s width:

- Set `width:100%` to the table
- Set `width:70%` to the container `div`.

Moreover, you have `width="10px"` on the top cells. If the table has a width of 70%, that's nonsense.

**Edit:**

I have fixed for IE 7 (and before), because if you set `display:inline-block` to an element which is a block, it continues being a block, so you have to set `diplay:inline` in order to make it be `display:inline-block`:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]><style>
.wraptocenter>div{
    display:inline;
}
</style><![endif]-->
```

Moreover, the white spaces between the `<span>` and the `<div>` are shown on some browsers, so the table isn't completely centered.

The solution is:

```
.wraptocenter {
    font-size:0;
}
.wraptocenter>div{
    font-size:16px; /* Or whatever you want */
}
```

(Font: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8902198/1529630, it's a great idea because in this case using floating would break the centering)

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/FW2Af/2/

**Edit 3:**

You say that on IE 8 nothing is shown. For me it works but instead of a black border, it's white. Fixed here: http://jsfiddle.net/FW2Af/3/

```
.wraptocenter td{
    border:1px solid black;
}
```