# Rolling my own simple 3 column grid, where is my math going wrong?

Tags: css, less

```
@nColumns: 3;
@sSurfaceWidth: 960px;
@sGutter: 10px;
@sBaseEntityWidth: (@sSurfaceWidth / @nColumns) - (@sGutter * 4);
@sBaseEntityHeight: 200px;

.entity {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: @sGutter;

    &.small {
        width: @sBaseEntityWidth;
        height: @sBaseEntityHeight;
    }
    &.medium {
        width: (@sBaseEntityWidth * 2) + (@sGutter * 2);
        height: @sBaseEntityHeight;
    }
    &.large {
        width: (@sBaseEntityWidth * 3) + (@sGutter * 4);
        height: @sBaseEntityHeight;
    }
}
```

And here is the result (Yellow line added for emphasis):

[image]

**update**: Removed shadows to ensure that wasn't causing an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be whitespace added between `inline-block` elements. When creating `inline-block` grids there needs to be no whitespace in your markup between each `li`.

This is usually achieved one of two ways. Either remove it:

```
<li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li>
```

Which can be formatted for readability like so:

```
<li>
    Item 1
</li><li>
    Item 2
</li>
```

Or use HTML comments to remove whitespace:

```
<li>Item 1</li><!--
--><li>Item 2</li>
```

This is the one drawback of using `inline-block` for layout, but once you know the trick it's not a big deal. It just makes your markup look ugly!

Another trick to using inline-block for layout: Add the declaration `vertical-align:top` to your `.entity` items. This eliminates vertical whitespace, and fixes alignment issues when the items are of varying heights.

Comment: Holy crap that was it... I'm not using li but divs.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Jonathan Nicol for the answer, but in case anyone else finds this, here is a neat way to work around this issue without compromising readability.  Set the font-size to 0 on the parent element, as [suggested in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097006/removing-whitespace-between-html-elements-when-using-line-breaks).

Comment: This technique can be good in situations where you have no control over the markup. I prefer to do it in markup rather than bloat my CSS by setting a small font size then resetting it again, but it's good to have a few options up your sleeve!