# HTML - Line break gets interpreted as whitespace character

Tags: php, html, whitespace, line-breaks, css

When coding in **HTML & PHP**, **line breaks** get interpreted as a **space** character. This can be problematically when using a list in order to achieve a horizontal menu because the space changes the padding unpredictably. I use this workaround for this:

**Note:** The `<li>` elements will have a `display: inline(-block);` property.

```
<ul>
    <li>...</li><?php
    ?><li>...</li><?php
    ?><li>...</li><?php
    ?><li>...</li><?php
    ?><li>...</li>
</ul>
```

This is really sad. I don't think it is supposed to be that way. I also don't want to mess up the code in a different way by say... add both `</li>` and the next `<li>` on one line (which is essentially the same as above).

**Question:** Is there a best practice solution for this?

Comment: Try using <br/> tag in html

Comment: If you are trying to just have the source have a line break, maybe use "\r\n". As @arkascha says, it shouldn't effect the actual display if they run together in the source....provided this is infact what you are referring to...

Comment: That is perfectly fine. It simply is a fact that whitespaces (whichever) have no layouting effect in html markup. That is by design. Instead you have to use explicit linebreaks or styling for the effect you desire.

Comment: But the white space separates the `<li>` elements by the width of its character. How do you *style* that away?

Comment: Asking for “best practice solution” tends to be primarily opinion-based, especially when no criteria have been set or they are esthetical (what the code looks like).

Comment: The criteria is to avoid the php tags used in the example and get a result without padding producing white spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After giving this some more research, I came up with the solution. Like **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097006/removing-whitespace-between-html-elements-when-using-line-breaks)**, people try to advertise my problem to others as a solution, which I won't accept.

But it's so simple. Don't use inline-block

```
.horizontal-menu ul li
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

But use table-cell!

```
.horizontal-menu ul li
{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Next time I have a similar issue, I will just try out more `display` options :)