# horizontal line between circles with transparent background

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to draw a horizontal line between empty circles (no background), How can I draw a line from one circle to other to match exactly without entering the other circle or not reach it?

I did the sample using [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rWmPde)

```css
#wizard {
  background-color: #eee;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
}
#wizard .step {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-right: 3em;
  margin-left: 3em;
  position: relative;
}
#wizard .step:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: auto;
  right: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
}
#wizard .step:last-child:after {
  display: none;
}
#wizard .step span {
  padding: 11px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wizard">
  <div class="step active">
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="step">
    <span>2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="step">
    <span>3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to absolutely position your `#wizard .step::after` pseudo-element, you need to know 2 things:

1. Where it should begin
2. How long it should be

You can see where it should begin, given that your `#wizard .step` has a border of `1px`, a padding of `2px` and a content width of `40px`.

`1px` + `2px` + `40px` + `2px` + `1px` = `46px`

So your position styles need to include `left: 46px`:

```
#wizard .step::after {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 46px;
}
```

As for how long it needs to be, it needs to span the `margin-right` of the current `#wizard .step` and then the `margin-left` of the next `#wizard .step`.

Since these are both `3em`, you can give it your `#wizard .step::after` pseudo-element a `width` of `6em`.

Putting it all together:

```css
#wizard {
  background-color: #eee;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:15px;
}

#wizard .step {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-right: 3em;
  margin-left: 3em;
  position: relative;
}

#wizard .step::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 46px;
  width: 6em;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
}

#wizard .step:last-child::after {
  display:none;
}

#wizard .step span {
    padding: 11px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wizard">
  <div class="step active">
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="step">
    <span>2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="step">
    <span>3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**N.B.** It's really not clear to me why, but though the result from the approach above should be flawless, the actual result includes tiny gaps - giving every impression of being from a 1950s text-book.

If you want to eliminate these gaps, use the following style declarations, instead:

```
#wizard .step::after {
left: 45px;
width: 6.3em;
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just use `left: 100%` instead of being a math ninja?

Comment: Hah. Fair question. Force of habit, I guess - I very rarely use `%` for anything.

Comment: I isolated the problem, and it is due to some whitespace, which you can select moving the mouse from one all the way to three. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/0bh5401w/).

Comment: You can see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097006/removing-whitespace-between-html-elements-when-using-line-breaks). It's related.

Comment: Thanks for answers, it looks great.. but this will be complicated if the wizard is responsive .. :\

Comment: That;s the advantage of using `ems` as your unit of length - you can declare  a different `#wizard {font-size: **px;}` for different `@media` queries and each time, that style rule will reset what `1em` is equal to. Alternatively you can use `vw` as your unit of length, which will resize itself, even in the absence of `@media` queries.

Answer (score 4):

Since your `margin-right` and `margin-left` are both `3em`, try using `6em` instead of `100%`

```
 left:auto;
 right:-6em;
 width:6em;
```

That leaves a little space, but you can tweak it:

```
right:-6.3em;
width:6.3em;
```