# Formatting divs inside div container

Tags: html, css

I made a simple example to test this out. I have one wrapper `div` with two other `div` elements inside it set to `display: inline-block;`. The two inner `div` elements fall on the same line, but how do I get them centered on the half of the main `div` they belong to?  For example, the blue box in the middle of the left side of the main `div` and the red box in the middle of the right side of the main `div`.  Code and screenshot below.

[image]

Also, the inspector shows a width of 204px for the `main-box` `div` and even when I set `padding` and `margin` to 0 there's still a gap on the bottom between the blue/red boxes and the border of the `main-box`.  How do I get rid of the gap?

```css
.box-test {
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
}

#main-box {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-box">
  <div id="blue" class="box-test"></div>
  <div id="red" class="box-test"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905827/why-does-my-image-have-space-underneath (for the vertical space)

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-do-i-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements (for the horizontal space)

Answer (score 4):

Use flexbox and `margin:auto` on both elements and they will get centred like you want and you will also get rid of all the whitespace issues:

```css
.box-test {
  height: 200px;
  margin:auto;
  width: 30%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
}

#main-box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-box">
  <div id="blue" class="box-test"></div>
  <div id="red" class="box-test"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you should use is a flexbox for the wrapper. When defining `space-around` for the 'horizontal alignment' you will get what you want.

For more details on flexbox see [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#main-box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.box-test {
  height: 200px;
  width: 30%;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-box">
  <div id="blue" class="box-test"></div>
  <div id="red" class="box-test"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox with property `justify-content: space-around` on the wrapper.

```css
.box-test {
  height: 200px;
  width: 30%;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
}

#main-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-box">
  <div id="blue" class="box-test"></div>
  <div id="red" class="box-test"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#main-box {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size:0;
}
```

Why it is so?
Please read this:

https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

[Removing whitespace between HTML elements when using line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097006/removing-whitespace-between-html-elements-when-using-line-breaks)

https://jsfiddle.net/evzckd3w/