# Unexpected white space in a nested <a> and <span> elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is my HTML and CSS code -

```css
.screenReaderOnly {
  width: 1px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<p>Please click on this
  <a href="mailto:XXX@XXX.XXX">link
    <span class="screenReaderOnly">Opens in new mail window</span>
  </a>.</p>
```

In the output there is a weird white space between the word `link` and `.` - why is this happening? and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097006/removing-whitespace-between-html-elements-when-using-line-breaks

Comment: make the `a` to be `display: inline-block;` (will try to find a better duplicate)

Comment: and don't repeat the same question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/61405265/8620333) even if you think that the duplicate isn't suitable

Answer (score 0):

It happens because interpreters condense spaces and newlines into a single space. The easiest way to get rid of it is to condense everything in one line.

```css
.screenReaderOnly {
    position: static;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<p>Please click on this
  <a href="mailto:XXX@XXX.XXX">link<span class="screenReaderOnly">Opens in new mail window</span></a>.</p>
```